# What value assumes an uninitialized variable using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I have this situation:

In a controller I have

```
# first statement
if a == true
  flag = true
end

# second statement
if flag == true
  // code1
else
  // code2
end
```

If `a` is false, what happens in the `if` statement without having initialized the `flag` variable? That is, is the `flag` variable "always"/"in any case" set to NOT TRUE?

Is it a safe approach?

Comment: Did you mean to use a capital A? Something starting with a capital letter is a constant.

Comment: You have right! It is a variable!!! Sorry, I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unassigned variable is equal to `nil` but constants work a little differently. With a variable anything other than `nil` or `false` will evaluate to true. With a constant you need to use `definded?(CONSTANT)` so your code would look like this:

```
# first statement
flag = A if defined?(A)

# second statement
if flag
  puts "Code 1"
else
  puts "Code 2"
end

# Or if you don't need the flag variable
if defined?(A) && A
  puts "Code 1"
else
  puts "Code 2"
end
```

Output:

```
Code 2
Code 2
```

Comment: Just to know, I updated just a little bit the question after the @Mike Bethany comment.

Comment: Ah, OK, that's what I thought but didn't want to assume. In that case the flag variable is redundant and you can just test `if a`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this sort of thing out in `irb`:

```
>> if false
>>   foo = "bar"
>>   end
=> nil
>> foo
=> nil
```

So you can see that even though the `if` condition is false, the `foo` variable is introduced (it is `nil`, which will be treated the same as `false` in your `if`, so you are safe).  I suspect that this is because `if` statements don't introduce a new scope.  See:

```
>> if true
>>   bar = "baz"
>>   end
=> "baz"
>> bar
=> "baz"
```

One final thought:  If `A` is really just a boolean, you could set `flag = A` and avoid the `if` altogether.

Comment: Just to know, I updated just a little bit the question after the @Mike Bethany comment.